# Android Preferences onBackButton

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

i'm saving the users login information to SharedPreferences, so he only has to configure his login data once.

This is my onBackPressed method in my Preferences.class (extends PreferenceActivity):

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //Login again
    Intent intent = new Intent(Preferences.this, LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

**What I need is a if-condition which checks, if the preferences changed or not**.:

If the user opens the Preferences Activity (edit: from any View(!)), and does not change anything and clicks the backbutton -> just go back to last state.

If the preferences changed: call LoginActivity.

Couldnt find a solution yet and the LoginActivity gets called whenever i hit the backbutton.

Thanks in advance,
Marley

Comment: use a preference listener

Comment: here you are launching loginActivity only.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine if there was a change in `SharedPreferences` you have to assign a `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` to your `SharedPreferences` object like this:

```
prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
```

in this case I'm doing it in my `Application` class that's implementing:

```
public class YambaAppObj extends Application implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
```

Then you will have to override:

```
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key)
{
    //this method will be called when preferences are changed.
    //do here what you want to record the change
    Log.d(TAG , "onSharedPreferenceChanged for:" + key);
}
```

and then you could check this record in your `onBackPressed()` method  of your `Preferences Activity`  and act accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` or (depending on what you really meany by `changed`) you can try utilising `onSharedPreferenceChanged()` like:

```
protected Boolean mPrefsChanged = false;

@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged( SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
                                                                  String key ) {
    mPrefsChanged = true;
}
```

of course it's far from perfect, but at least you got more options

Comment: what the point in giving the same answer almost 10 minutes after?

Comment: If its far from perfect, what can I do better?